# Please tell me what is wrong with this code

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I wrote some code for a hackerrank but it didn't work with some of the test cases, what is wrong with it?

The problem is called Nested Lists, here is the link: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/nested-list/problem?h_r=next-challenge&h_v=zen

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    students = []
    for _ in range(int(input())):
        name = input()
        score = float(input())
        students.append([name, score])

# making a  set of all the scores
n = len(students)
score_list = []

for i in range(n):
    score_list.append(students[i][1])
score_list.sort()
score_set = set(score_list)

required_score = list(score_set)[1]

# making a list of all the people with the required score
people = []
for i in range(n):
    if students[i][1] == required_score :
        people.append(students[i][0])

people.sort() 
# printing each line
for i in range(len(people)):
    print(people[i])
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! What _is_ wrong with it? What do you expect as an output and what do you get? Instead of linking to a lengthy description, summarise your issue. Please read these help pages on [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to create a [Minimal, Reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: "it didn't work". Nobody here has any idea what that means. Did you get error? Provide stack trace and [mcve] (e.g., example input data, etc.).

Comment: instead of `for i in range(n): score_list.append(students[i][1])` you can do `for item in students: score_list.append(item[1])` - it will be more readable for human.

Comment: instead of `for i in range(len(people)): print(people[i])` you can do `for item in people: print(item)` or even in one line `print( "\n".join(people) )`

Comment: you don't need `if __name__ == '__main__':`

Comment: test code on some examples and use `print()` to see values in variables in different moments. It can help to see mistakes.

Comment: @furas I pretty sure `if __name__ == '__main__':` is part of the Hackerrank's stub code.

Comment: @shash678 right now I tested it without `if __name__ == '__main__':` and it works. I think someone put `if __name__ == '__main__':` in starting code but it is not necessery to use it.

Comment: don't use `set()` - you don't need it and it doesn't have to keep order in sorted list.

Answer (score 1):

First, you can make this code more "pythonic".

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    students = []
    for _ in range(int(input())):
        name = input()
        score = float(input())
        students.append([name, score])

# making a  set of all the scores
score_list = [student[1] for student in students]
```

This is called a "list comprehension". It makes it much easier to create lists than the classic "append in a for loop" method.

```
score_list.sort()
score_set = set(score_list)

required_score = list(score_set)[1]
```

I'm not quite sure what you're doing here. If you're going to make a set from the list of scores, it doesn't need to be sorted. Then you convert the set back to a list, and take the second item of the list. I would assume converting a set to a list gives you a list in a random order. The way it's implemented in python, that might not be the case, but semantically it doesn't make sense that you would get any reliable ordering from converting a set to a list.

```
# making a list of all the people with the required score
people = []
for i in range(n):
    if students[i][1] == required_score :
        people.append(students[i][0])
```

I'm going to spend a little time on this for loop here. First, python offers an easy way to iterate through a list. You don't need to access each item by index:

```
people = []
for student in students:
    if student[1] == required_score :
        people.append(student[0])
```

Next, because your students list contains lists of two items, you can unpack those lists in the for loop:

```
people = []
for name, score in students:
    if score == required_score :
        people.append(name)
```

And again, this can be done in one line by converting to a list comprehension, but some might prefer the above version because it's easier to read:

```
people = [name for name, score in students if score == required_score]

# printing each line
for student in sorted(people):
    print(student)
```

Notice the changes I made in that last loop. As for what's wrong, I would guess it's the way you're getting the number for required_score, but without seeing the input and expected output it's hard to know.